# Looking for informations & datasheet of OSS-4ES

Tags: components, identification

I have an (old) dip8 component I cannot identify properly.

It is quite unusual & nice so I'm looking for its datasheet or information about it.

The date(s) code(s) I found seems to be 90's for each information & photo I can find over the internet until now.

[image]

I thought it was photo resistor array or photodiode array but while testing it this way determinate it is not.

Any idea about what this OSS-4ES device is?
And where to get a datasheet?

Comment: why do you think it's not a linear photodiode array?

Comment: tests eliminate the diode array possibility. as mentionned ;)

Comment: Yes I was interested in what tests, and how you reached that conclusion, as it's clearly an important piece of information that will help people answer your question.

Comment: I used  an emitting photo diode to light the cells & used a diode tester on each pin combinason  none was neither opened, nor detecting a 0.6 or similare voltage droping ; then I conclued it wasn't photodiode array.

Comment: That's not how photo-diodes work. You apply a very weak reverse bias (ie you connect the diode in the way it wouldn't normally conduct) with a large resistor to limit the current. Then when light shines on the diode, a very weak current flows through the diode in the direction it normally doesn't.

Comment: so the diode s "conductive" so I had to detect that .. this isn't the case :)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but if you do the standard test for a photodiode (hook it up with some bias, and see if light makes a current flow), it will tell you if you have a photodiode, (or even a phototransistor). If I understand you, you appear to have decided because it doesn't conduct in at least one direction it's not a photodiode, so it could still be a phototransistor.

Comment: non no no i tested each combination on both directions WHEN the cells is recieving light AND when not :) I hope it is more clear now

Comment: and you measured the current? rather than just used the diode test mode of a DMM

Comment: I did & detect nothing

Comment: (Sorry for being a pain) - did you see if they're tiny solar cells?

Comment: I'll check but time code & so small ones .... seems strange :)

Comment: hello, I made a video to check if I can get this componant identification : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOey7G8wiLk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOey7G8wiLk)

Comment: OK : on last news it seems to come from a mouse type vkm674 and to be a laser sensitive resistors & laser sensitive diodes network.  But unfortunatly my device seems not to work properly anymore. https://www.facebook.com/groups/Cyrob.org/permalink/1658220110992891/

Comment: I also have two of these with the same question. Pins 1, 4, 5, 8 are all tied together on both DIPs. No connectivity on any other pins in both polarities. [Photo of devices on breadboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBRWN.jpg)